# Analog PID vs digital PID?

Tags: microcontroller, control, control-system, pid-controller

What is the difference between hardware/standalone pid controller and that implemented in programming  using microcontroller?

I have also placed below links of two stand alone pid controllers

https://akytec.de/en/trm212.html

Here is a standalone temperature control pid controller

https://realpars.com/pid-controller/

Comment: One is done with amplifiers and one is done in code.

Comment: one is heavier than the other ... you did not specify clearly what you are actually wanting to know

Comment: One is more flexible (the one done in code like on a microcontroller or processor) and one is faster (the one done in hardware like on done on an FPGA).

Comment: Please tell us what differences, beyond the obvious ones, are you asking about?

Comment: @DKNguyen not necessarily – the speed of a PID controller is defined by its parameters, and you can (and would, often) build a slow analog controller, or a fast digital one.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Are you defining fast as in fast response? When I say fast, I just mean something more akin to "execution time" or latency rather than the actual response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analog controller is continuous and is analyzed as such. The benefits are potentially limitless resolution. An analog controller is limited by the noise of the amplifiers. The downsides of an analog controller are that they can be hard to tune, because more often then not it involves using physical components such as variable resistors and capacitors.

Digital controllers are limited by the sampling rate and by the resolution of the ADC's and DAC's. The benefits are easy tuneability and additional control logic that can be used with programming the digital system.

Digital controllers work well for most applications nowadays, it is rare to see a fully analog controller in most industries.

If your talking about "hardware" meaning digital PID controllers implemented with an FPGA vs a microcontroller, then the main differences will be in the loop timing (the update rate of the loop and the resolution of the ADC's and DAC's.

FPGA's and ASIC's can provide much faster loop timing as the control loops can be made to respond much faster than a micro controller.

Comment: People seem so to be treating "hardware" as synonymous with "analog". I don't think that's true.

Comment: True, the first controllers were built from flywheels and other mechanical limiters.

Comment: I was more referring to FPGAs where it's both digital and hardware. Personally, I would consider most mechanical anything that operates on a continuous scale to be the very analog.

Comment: @DKNguyen -- people are treating it this way because they're trying to make the question make sense.  The asker has posted a similar question showing that, indeed, you are correct that the assumption is wrong, but it isn't helping the question make more sense.